# Отправка файлов из папки на E-mail

Tags: c#

Есть папкf в ней файлы .txt их много и с разными названиями,как отправить их на почту?Код указан ниже

КОД

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.ru", 2525); // Здесь указываем смтп сервер и порт, который мы будем использовать 
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("login@mail.ru", "password"); // Указываем логин и пароль для авторизации

string msgFrom = "login@mail.ru"; // Указываем поле, от кого письмо 
string msgTo = "login@mail.ru"; // Указываем поле, кому письмо будет отправлено 
string msgSubject = "Письмо из c#"; // Указываем тему пиьсма

string msgBody = String.Format("", 
ToString(), textBox1.Text); // Тут мы формируем тело письма

MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(msgFrom, msgTo, msgSubject, msgBody); // Создаем письмо, из всего, что сделали выше

try 
{ 
client.Send(msg); // Отправляем письмо 
} 
catch { 
}
```

Что надо дописать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот это

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.IO;

....
Directory.GetFiles(folderWithFiles, "*.txt").ToList().ForEach(
    name => msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(name, MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

А я бы добавил еще архивирование файлов в ZIP (если это не противоречит требованиям задачи). Текстовые файлы очень хорошо архивируются. Посмотрите вот эту библиотеку (стандартные средства майскрософт GZip создает не совсем корректный zip, поэтому лучше его не использовать)

http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/